# heroku push code error ruby on rails mac os

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, macos, heroku

This is my output at mac terminal and heroku master branch:

```
[remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/projectname.git'
    In heroku
    -----> Ruby app detected
    -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
    -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
    -----> Installing dependencies using 1.9.7
           Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
           You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
           your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
           updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
           You have added to the Gemfile:
           * ruby (= 2.0.0)
           * pg (= 0.17.1)
           Bundler Output: You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
           your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
           updated Gemfile.lock to version control.

           You have added to the Gemfile:
           * ruby (= 2.0.0)
           * pg (= 0.17.1)
     !
     !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
     !
     !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

Comment: Where is your question?

Comment: no its not duplicate i search all questions but no one solve my issue

Comment: This is not even a question, how it can be a duplicate.

Comment: heroku push code error ruby on rails mac os  how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to do `bundle install` first, so that your gem.lock file is up to date before pushing to heroku.....

Comment: i already do that bundle install work fine this is the issue of heroku

Comment: bundle install run fine , issue comes only at heroku push

Comment: solved i put my pg and simple-form gem in development in gemfile